# Button Click Event does not fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, buttonclick

I have the following ASP-Markup:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" meta:resourcekey="btnSubmit" CssClass="submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

And the following Code-Behind:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

For some reason, the Button Click Event does not fire ... it works on other pages with the exact same markup, I've tried doing "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i" - didn't make a difference.

Also, there is nothing AJAXy going on in this page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Dennis

Comment: Do you have validation controls on your page?

Comment: Yes, I do ... how could I forget that!? How exactly might they be compromising that event to fire? I haven't specified CausesValidation for the Button.

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors on your page?

Comment: Alrighty, turns out CausesValidation is true by default, if you'd be kind enough to repost this as an answer I'll gladly mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try disabling the ValidationControls and see if the event fires.

Also try adding `CauseValidation=false` to the markup of your Button.