# Not able to call User control button click event when loaded dynamically into another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, buttonclick

I am writing a project that load the list of products and then provide an option to delete them. ASP.NET C#

so have created a user control for this purpose.

The user control has product image, name , and has one button for delete.
and this user control is loaded dynamically into a page lets say Products page.

but i have loaded an array of user control dynamically into Products page.

Below is the code for it.

```
            ProductInfo ib = (ProductInfo)LoadControl("ProductInfo.ascx");
            ProductName = "xyz"; 
            /**and so on*//
            spn_list.Controls.Add(ib);
```

and now a list is displayed with each product from database and each of them also has delete button.

but when i click on the delete button, it does not calls he event. none of them.

have also tried to use break Point but it does not reaches there.
?????

also tried This example

[Button Click Event does not fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487383/button-click-event-does-not-fire)

but does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user control must be loaded in the `Page_Init` method not the `Page_Load`. If it is done in Page_Load then it won't be added to ViewState so problems will occurr

Also wire the events on every page load not just the first load as is more usual.

```
if(!Page.PostBack) 
{     
    control.EventRaised += new EventHandler(EventResponse) 
}
```

**is wrong** - this event will disappear when the page reloads. Events wiring doesn't perisist on post back.

Comment: Thanks For the Answer. Got the solution it was `!Postback` That was Stopping me from Calling the event. now able to Delete it...